# JFreeChart - Problemas ao customizar gráfico

Tags: java, gui, jfreechart

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que possui um gráfico dinâmico.
Estou precisando alterar o estilo do gráfico, mas não estou conseguindo.

Preciso que ele tenha fundo branco, linha azul com marcadores quadrados e tenha os valores sobre cada marcador.

Já busquei diversos tutoriais na internet e só consegui customizar a cor da linha. Sempre encontro algum erro ou o código não funciona.

Segue meu código:

```
public void montaImagem(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm pform, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException {
    DefaultCategoryDataset graficoLinhas = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    // * Crio o dataSet graficoLinhas a partir da resposta do banco *
    try{
        JFreeChart objetoGrafico = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Taxa(%)",
                "Meses", //linha X
                "", //linha Y
                graficoLinhas, //gráfico gerado acima
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, //orientação do gráfico
                true, 
                true,
                false);

        //Setando BG para BRANCO - único comando customizador que parece funcionar.
        objetoGrafico.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE); 
        // * A partir daqui, gero a imagem de resposta, o código funciona como deveria *
```

Como faço para setar a linha para Azul, inserir os markers e fazer os valores que estão no `graficoLinhas` aparecerem sobre esses markers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Irei partir do que você postou na questão, então as duas linhas abaixo criam o gráfico e configura o fundo dele para a cor branca:

```
final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Taxa (%)", "Meses", "", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
```

Iniciado o gráfico, temos que recuperar o [`Plot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/Plot.html), que é o corpo do gráfico, onde são plotadas as linhas, pontos, etc e que por isto é onde estão os outros objetos que precisamos alterar.

Como no exemplo usamos um [`DefaultCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/DefaultCategoryDataset.html), iremos recuperar logo um [`CategoryPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CategoryPlot.html):

```
// recupera o ploter, estamos recuparando um "CategoryPlot" devido ao dataset usado
final CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
```

Recuperado o objeto que representa a área de plotagem, vamos também configurá-la para a cor branca, deste jeito:

```
// torna o fundo da área de plotagem do gráfico branda
plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
```

Na área de plotagem temos um objeto que é responsável pela renderização do gráfico, um objeto do tipo [`CategoryItemRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/CategoryItemRenderer.html). Como estamos usando [`CategoryPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CategoryPlot.html), podemos recuperar um [`LineAndShapeRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/LineAndShapeRenderer.html), de acordo com a documentação:

> A renderer that draws shapes for each data item, and lines between data items (for use with the [`CategoryPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/CategoryPlot.html) class).

Então, para recuperá-lo é basicamento isto:

```
// recupera o renderer que represneta a linha plotada
final LineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (LineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
```

Com a linha abaixo tornamos os marcadores quadrados visíveis.

```
// tornando os marcadores quadrados visíveis
renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
```

Para customizá-los de outras formas, olhe na documentação do renderizador como pode fazer isto.

A linha de código abaixo torna a linha do gráfico azul. O marcador quadrado, por padrão, segue esta mesma cor:

```
// altera a cor da linha
renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLUE);
```

Por último, vamos criar um padrão de formatação para o label. [`StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/labels/StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator.html) recebe como segundo argumento um [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html), criei um [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) simples mesmo:

```
// cria o de formatação para o label do item
final DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#0.##");
renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator("{2}", format));
```

Depois de termos criado o padrão de formatação que queremos para o label dos itens, e de termos configurado este padrão, agora basta habilitar a exibição dos labels no gráfico. Para isto, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
// torna o label visível para cada item
renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
```

Pronto, já temos nosso gráfico configurado. Para testar, considerando o `dataset` abaixo:

```
final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
dataset.addValue(15.7, "taxa", "JAN");
dataset.addValue(21.2, "taxa", "FEV");
dataset.addValue(20.7, "taxa", "MAR");
dataset.addValue(18, "taxa", "ABR");
dataset.addValue(22.9, "taxa", "MAI");
dataset.addValue(13.4, "taxa", "JUN");
dataset.addValue(17.8, "taxa", "JUL");
dataset.addValue(9.7, "taxa", "AGO");
dataset.addValue(14.3, "taxa", "SET");
dataset.addValue(13.8, "taxa", "OUT");
dataset.addValue(12.4, "taxa", "NOV");
dataset.addValue(11.7, "taxa", "DEZ");
```

e as customizações citadas acima, obtemos este resultado:

[image: Exemplo de Gráfico em Linhas]

Comment: Obrigado, @Bruno César. Vou verificar se consigo colocar para funcionar.

Comment: É isso aí. Funcionou muito bem. Graças às suas explicações, consegui fazer e também alterar um ou outro detalhe. Obrigado mesmo