# Framework para Geração de Gráficos para um Sistema Desktop em Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, gráfico

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um sistema `desktop` em `Java` e nele preciso prover visualizações de dados através de gráficos. Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece, ouviu falar ou já utilizou algum `framework` para tal proposito?

Obs I: Não quero gerar relatórios em `PDF`, quero criar gráficos dinamicamente dentro de um `Frame` ou `Panel` com base nos dados que eu informar.

Obs II: Sei que o `Jasper Studio` disponibiliza em seus relatórios essa funcionalidade de por gráficos, mas alguém sabe dizer se ele se encaixa ao que eu quero?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) e veja se é o que precisa. [Aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60859/60899#60899) tem uma resposta com exemplo de uso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um bom framework para o que você quer é:

**JOpenChart**

http://jopenchart.sourceforge.net/

recomendo este também:

**ChartFX for Java Desktop**

https://www.softwarefx.com/sfxjavaproducts/cfxforjava/feats_desktop.aspx

Os dois proveem maneiras de gerar Gráficos e atualizá-los dinamicamente em um ambiente desktop

Comment: Obrigado Filipe, irei estudar as ferramentas propostas. Abraço.

Comment: JOpenChart tá descontinuado tem um bom tempo já, não? A outra parece bacana, sabe se tem versão free?